# Does Restkit handle entity uniqueness through to CoreData Sqlite?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, restkit

when using RestKit to download json objects from Restful service and setting the entity in the mapping. Does the entity uniqueness extend through to the CoreData sqlite database?
If so how is it achieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using RestKit 0.20, uniqueness is achieved by specifying `identificationAttributes` when defining your entity mapping. If you don't do this, new records will be created each time you perform an object mapping.

For more information, see https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping, specifically the Core Data section.